# How can I unit test Flex applications?

Tags: apache-flex, flexunit

Flex is a client-side language and based on events. How can such events be mocked to allow unit testing?

Comment: Frankly, I know flexunit little.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [FlexUnit](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexunit/FlexUnit) and [FlexMonkey](http://www.gorillalogic.com/flexmonkey)

If you are writing your components to user Interfaces rather than concrete components, mocking objects is as simple as a new implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There are also real mock libraries for AS3. Take a look at this tutorial:

http://www.allenmanning.com/?p=7

and the Mockolate library. I have actually used mock-as3, which is Mockolate's ancestor.  With it you can create fake objects that act like dummy facades for things irrelevant to your testing: this way you can focus on testing a specific piece of code (be it in a UI class or not) decoupling it from its dependencies.